# How to loop a json array and update links

Tags: jquery, json

On page load, I do one call to get the current status of all the favourite links (display the right message aka: click to subscribe, click to unsubscribe.

Final Code! :) Thanks for your help guys, please check post revisions to see the issue.

```
$(InitFavorite);

function InitFavorite(){

    var jList = $(".favourite_link");
    var ids_to_check = {};//new Array();

    $.each(jList, function () {
        var id = this.id;
        var object = id.split("_");
        if (!ids_to_check[object[1]]) {
            ids_to_check[object[1]] = [];
        }
        ids_to_check[object[1]].push(object[0]);
    });

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/user/subscription/favourite-listing',
        data: ids_to_check,
        dataType: 'json',
         beforeSend: function(x) {
              if(x && x.overrideMimeType) {
               x.overrideMimeType("application/json;charset=UTF-8");
          }
         },
        error: function() {
            //could not load favourites
        },
        success: function(returned_values) {

            $.each(returned_values.favourites.Clip, function(i, item) {
                $('#'+i+'_Clip').html(''+item+'');
            });
            $.each(returned_values.favourites.Playlist, function(i, item) {
                $('#'+i+'_Playlist').html(''+item+'');
            });
        }
    });
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem you've run into?

Comment: what happens on success?

Comment: refer this link [JSON.org](http://www.json.org/)

Comment: application/j-son should be application/json

Answer (score 0):

You must parse your text so it becomes an object instead of JSON (plain-text):

```
var o = eval('(' + returned_values + ')');
```

then you should be able to use `o` as the object:

```
alert(o.env); // Gives "development"
```

more specifically:

```
    success: function(returned_values) {
        var o = eval('(' + returned_values + ')');
        $.each(o, function(i, item) {
            console.log(item);
        });
    }
```

Comment: Just tried this, nothing happens, no alert and console.logging it returns nothing either